# Selenium with JavaScript Enabled Doesn't Skip <noscript> Tag

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, redirect, scrapy, user-agent

I'm using (headless) Selenium to scrape https://www.flashscore.com/, but I find that even though I'm using a desktop User Agent, I'm still getting redirected to the mobile site https://www.flashscore.mobi, because of this refresh line in the html:

```
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://www.flashscore.mobi/'" />
</noscript>
```

I'm trying to understand why Selenium redirects, despite having Javascript enabled (and thus it should ignore html in the noscript tag?).

Comment: It's probably not the user agent. The default headless window size is very small. Your site has a reactive design therefore scales the  UI to a mobile layout based on window size. Try it - open chrome and make your window smaller.  Set the window size or can you share your code?

Comment: Thanks! I've since found the culprit html lines and edited my question.

Comment: Do you want to share your code? - without headers or options my selenium launches to the desktop site without issue.

Comment: include your webdriver initialization code.  Javascript will be on by default for any browser... so you may be setting a preference in there.  (or using a profile which has it turned off?)